# How to choose default Subversion (svn) version to use when 2 versions are installed

Tags: linux, svn, centos

I have 2 version of subversion installed on my server. Version 1.6.3 and 1.8.0 located in /usr/local/bin and /usr/bin.

The server is using version 1.6.3 but I want to use version 1.8.0.

Is there a way to change the default svn commands folder?

How can I completly remove the old version and use the new one?

I'm on centos 5.9 with cpanel.

Answer (score 1):

You can run commands without a prefix when it's in your path:

```
echo $PATH
```

Most likely both executables are in your path. Your shell is using the first hit:

```
# which svn
/usr/bin/svn
```

If you like to use both version do:

```
cd /usr/bin
mv svn svn16
```

Now you can use "svn16" for version 1.6.3 and svn for the newer version.

If you like to completely remove svn 1.6.3 you can do this with the package manager.

```
yum list | grep subversion
```

Check if this is version 1.6.3, if it is:

```
yum remove subversion
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the *server* or the *client*?

On the server, it all depends what protocol you're running. If you're running under Apache HTPD, you need to find out what your Subversion plugins to HTTPD are. The Subversion client isn't used (except for the API libraries which I believe have the version number encoded on them and are executed with the version number on them).

On the client side, it all depends how you execute and what your path is.

I have a Mac, and on /usr/bin is Subversion 1.6 something. I too want to run SVN 1.8 client, so I installed it. It's in /opt/svn. I linked the various client programs for 1.8 into `/usr/local/bin`, and I've set my login path to be `/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:$HOME/bin`. This way, if there is a program in `/usr/local/bin` and in `/usr/bin` or `/bin`, the version in `/usr/local/bin` is executed. This allows me to replace the standard installed versions with the versions I prefer.

So:

- You talking about client or server.
- If it is server:

  - What protocol are you using?

    1. If it is `svnserve` what `svnserve` executable are you using (and the `svnadmin` that created your repository.
    2. If it is `Apache httpd`, how was that compiled and installed?